# ¿Cómo obligar a mi componente a renderizar después del setState?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo un `handlechange` para un componente. El código es el siguiente:

```
function insertData(newData) {
    return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newData) 
});
}

handleRowAdd = (newData) => 
              new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  resolve();
                    const data = this.state.data;
                    newData = insertData(newData);
                    newData.then(result => {
                        if(result.ok) {
                            return result.json()
                        }
                        throw new Error('Error al insertar valor.');
                    }).then(result => {
                        data.push(result);;
                        this.setState({data: data}, console.log(this.state.data));
                    }, error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }, 600);
              });
```

Este `handleRowAdd`, como pueden ver la idea es que inserte un dato en la BD a través de un api. La respuesta del API, es el valor que envié pero con el id de la base de datos que fue asignado y demás. Todo lo hace correcto, el problema es que al ejecutar `this.setState`, este no refresca mi componente, por lo que de nada me sirve devolver el valor ingresado si no puedo verlo. Buscando, encontré ese `forceUpdate`, pero no hace nada.

**Edición:**

Cambio de la función, la anterior no funcionaba por lo que la modifiqué y ahora el callback del `setState`, si devuelve el state modificado, pero sigue sin refrescar la pantalla. Encontré algo de `location.reload()`, pero quiero saber si es un error en mi lógica.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podrias intentar esto y ver si funciona, no estoy seguro si el detalle esta en el momento que haces el `data.push()`, borrar la variable data. 
`this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  data: prevState.data.push(result)
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias cosillas por solucionar, pero si todo te funciona tratare de "adivinar" el lugar donde este mal tu codigo.

**1.-const**

La diferencia entre `var`,`let` y `const` si bien no son tan amplias, si que son diferentes. Y lo que hace `const` es muy similar a lo que realiza `let` con la diferencia de que los valores de `const` no son mutables("no pueden cambiar").

Dicho esto quizá el error estuviera en:

```
const data = this.state.data;
```

Yo lo cambiaría por:

```
let data = [...this.state.data];
```

**2.- this dentro de la promesa**

No estoy seguro de esta opción, pero por alguna razón `this` no me funcionaba dentro de las promesas. Es decir si funciona pero no es el `this` de la clase, sino él de la promesa.(espero se entienda)

Entonces antes de utilizar `this` en la promesa utilizaba `_selft` que es una variable que creaba antes de entrar en la promesa.

```
let _selft=this;
new Promise(...
    const data = _selft.state.data;
    newData = insertData(newData);
    newData.then(...).then(result => {
        _selft.setState({data: newObject});
    })
```

**3.- Mi forma de hacer lo mismo**

Veo una promesa y un `setTimeout` no se el motivo pero no lo incluiré en el siguiente ejemplo que es como yo realizo una petición `fetch`.

```
async subirInfo(e){
    e.preventDefault();//evita la accion de una etiqueta button, a, submit
    //validar datos
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('nombre', this.state.form.nombre)
    //carga de datos
    try{
        let config = {
            method:'POST',
            header:{
                'Accept' : 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            body:formData
        }

        let res = await fetch(url,config);

        if(res.ok){//si la peticion fue exitosa retorna true
            let data = await res.json();//data es un objeto de propietario             
            this.setState({
                propietarios:this.state.propietarios.concat(data),
            })
        }else{
            console.log(error);
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Donde se encuentra dos palabra reservadas como `async` para especificar que la funcion es asyncrona y `await` que es para esperar la respuesta de la promesa `fetch`.

Tambien se puede aplicar en funciones flecha asi:

```
conts subirInfo= async event => {....}
//o asi
conts subirInfo= async (e) => {....} //jajaj no cambio nada.
```

Espero que con alguna de las opciones soluciones tu error.

Comment: Tienes razón, te diré que no me había fíjado del detalle del const, pero igual funcionó, lo que realmente resolvió el problema fue esta forma de declararlo: [...this.state.data]. Pero, ¿cuál es la diferencia, no deberían hacer lo mismo? Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

- React automaticamente renderiza cuando hay un cambio en el state, no
  tienes por que forzar el renderizado.
- El state en React reconoce cuando es el mismo objeto por lo que no
  estás cambiando de objeto realmente

Puedes intentar esto:

```
   handleRowAdd = (newData) => 
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
                const data = this.state.data;
                newData = insertData(newData);
                newData.then(result => {
                    if(result.ok) {
                        return result.json()
                    }
                    throw new Error('Error al insertar valor.');
                }).then(result => {

                    //DETALLE ESTÁ AQUÍ
                    const newObject = {...data};
                    newObject.push(result);;
                    this.setState({data: newObject});

                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }, 600);
          });
```

Con esto te aseguras de cambiar el state, espero te funcione